# query too slow - get and update records with linq query

Tags: c#, linq

i have this query

```
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    var countrylist = from country in countryList
                                 where
                                     (from state in stateList
                                      where
                                          (from city in cityList
                                           where
                                             city.CityID == item.CityID
                                           select new
                                           {
                                               city.CountryID
                                           }).Contains(new { StateID = state.StateID })
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          state.CountryID
                                      }).Contains(new { CountryID = country.CountryID })
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     CountryID = country.CountryIDD,
                                     Name = country.Name
                                 };

                item.Country = new Country();
                item.Country.CountryID = countrylist.Select(s => s.CountryID).FirstOrDefault();
                item.Country.Name = countrylist.Select(s => s.CountryName).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

it gets the CountryId and CountryName based on given cityID and then it updates the related object in collection. Now it runs in a loop , currently i have 5-10 items (test data) in collection and it takes noticeable time (noticeably slow). If on 5-10 items its slow, it will be way too slow on 100+ items. Is there another way i can make this thing better?

I will appreciate any sort of Help

Comment: Try using a join instead: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Simplify the query first. If you can't understand what it does, you can't make it go faster. Then check for missing indexes. Also, instead of executing the same query for each item, generate a list of item.CityID and use `where itemCities.Contains(city.CityID)`. This translates to a single query with an `IN (...)` clause, instead of 5-10 slow queries

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft i agree i dont know why i didn't think of that first

Comment: Are you comparing the right values? For example: `...select new { city.CountryID }).Contains(new { StateID = state.StateID })`- you are comparing country-id with state-id. And you can lose the `new { .. }`, just do this: `...select city.CountryID).Contains(state.StateID)`.

Comment: @Maarten Sorry but i am not quiet following?

Comment: Thanks Murray and Panagiotis, it really help. Thank again Panagiotis for pointing out making list for checking instead of executing query again and again...

Comment: You guys are awesome, i appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Murray Foxcroft's response I built up a new query.  I don't have the objects you are using, but I think it should look similar to this:

```
var countrylist = from country in countryList
            join state in stateList
            on country.CountryID = State.CountryID
            join city in cityList
            on state.StateID = city.StateID
            where
            city.CityID == item.CityID
            select new
            {
                CountryID = country.CountryIDD,
                Name = country.Name
            };
```

Comment: You stealing my thunder :)   Thanks for taking the time to give the OP a nicely coded answer.

Comment: Thank You for help

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that as your city has a CountryID field in it, you don't need to join to the state at all. This is simple code with no exception handling: you may want to try find a city then get the country in a try catch block.

```
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        var country = countryList.Find(c=> c.CountryID == cityList.Find(c => c.CityID == item.CityID).StateId);
        item.Country = newCountry
        {
            CountryID = country.CountryIDD,
            Name = country.Name
        };
    };
```

Comment: city doesn't have countryID field in it. Country has State and State has City. So City has StateID and State has CountryID

Comment: Ah, made the assumption based on the code: select new
                                           {
                                               city.CountryID
                                           }

Comment: yeah i agree, i made it way too complicated .. i think i was asleep when i was writing it?

Comment: Yeah, we've all been there!